# Karate: contains functionality

Tags: karate

I have the following where Im comparing responses of two envs on the fly.
In my case for some of the services the response json elements/array order is not mandatory, but for some its mandatory. So I used contains, but my doubt is if any of the elements/arrays is missing in any of the responses
say while comparing below two:

```
A: {
    "hotels": [
      { "roomInformation": [{ "roomPrice": 618.4 }], "totalPrice": 618.4  },
      { "roomInformation": [{ "roomPrice": 679.79}], "totalPrice": 679.79 }
    ]
  }

B:
{
    "hotels": [
      { "roomInformation": [{ "roomPrice": 618.4 }], "totalPrice": 618.4  },
      { "roomInformation": [{ "roomPrice": 680.79}], "totalPrice": 680.79 },
      { "roomInformation": [{ "roomPrice": 679.79}], "totalPrice": 679.79 }

    ]
  }
```

using the below match each with `contains` give positive result? please suggest

```
Feature: 
Background:

Scenario: test
        * json input = read('input.json')
        * def stage= call read('A.feature') input;
        * def prod = call read('B.feature') input;      
        #* def rp = $prod[*].response
        #* def rs = $stage[*].response
    #* match rs contains rp
    #* match each $prod[*].response[*] contains $stage[*].response
    # * match each $prod[*].response[*] contains $stage[*].response.[*]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is somewhat convoluted, making it harder to answer.

Also, your assert can be a partial list of the expected whole.  Use the `print` command to help you debug it.

```
* def roomPrices = response.hotels[*].totalPrice
* print roomPrices
* match roomPrices contains [ 680.79, 1.00 ]
```

Comment: In my case im comparing stage vs prod and comparing the whole response on the fly, both the regions have same data so both the results supposed to be same. For some of the services the order of response elements in JSON shuffles around, so when I do exact `match` (==) or even contains gives failure. My assumption was `contains` will give positive results if the order is different!

Comment: Personally, I never try to compare the entire response.   I usually will use `karate.filter` to narrow down response content to the area I want to diff.   Also, I just realized my example code above might not work the way it is.  Maybe change `assert` to `match` since the DSL `contains` operator is probably within the `match` operation.  I am still new to this stuff also.  (edited my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Since order is important and it is in a array/list, a "equals" check than "contains" works as desired:

The following code results in an error.

**Sample Code:**

```
Feature: Validation

    Scenario:

        * def stage =
        """
        {
            "hotels": [
            { "roomInformation": [{ "roomPrice": 618.4 }], "totalPrice": 618.4  },
            { "roomInformation": [{ "roomPrice": 679.79}], "totalPrice": 679.79 }
            ]
        }
        """
        * def prod =
        """
        {
            "hotels": [
            { "roomInformation": [{ "roomPrice": 679.79}], "totalPrice": 679.79 },
            { "roomInformation": [{ "roomPrice": 618.4 }], "totalPrice": 618.4  }
            ]
        }
        """
        * match  prod == stage
        #ERROR: path: $.hotels[0], actual: {roomInformation=[{"roomPrice":679.79}], totalPrice=679.79}, expected: {roomInformation=[{"roomPrice":618.4}], totalPrice=618.4}, reason: [path: $.hotels[0].roomInformation[0], actual: {roomPrice=679.79}, expected: {roomPrice=618.4}, reason: [path: $.hotels[0].roomInformation[0].roomPrice, actual: 679.79, expected: 618.4, reason: not equal (Double)]]
```